# How to change the device's keyboard to uppercase?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Here is my `input`:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Nickname</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="nickname" [(ngModel)]="nickname"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

How to change the device's keyboard to uppercase using Ionic 2?

Comment: I have another solution, where instead of making keyboard capitalised, whatever you type in from keyboard, will be capitalised in input field via CSS. In back-end, you will have the non-capitalised value only. But, you can manipulate it easily. Solution - add `text-transform: uppercase;` in input's css.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you just want to make all text inserted to that field uppercase, you can just add `text-transform: uppercase;` to the field's CSS and that will do it.

If you actually require that the user's keyboard changes to "uppercase mode", that wasn't possible until a while ago, but recent browsers (and Ionic) support a new attribute called `autocapitalize` which does exactly what you want: Input elements with the `autocapitalize` attribute set to true will make the virtual keyboard uppercase on mobile devices.

You can see more info on `autocapitalize` here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/autocapitalize

So you should change your `ion-input` to:

```html
<ion-input formControlName="nickname" 
           [(ngModel)]="nickname" 
           autocapitalize="characters">
</ion-input>
```

(The other `autocapitalize` options are "words" and "sentences", which I believe should be self-explanatory)

Just remember that the user can still turn their keyboard back to lower-case manually, so if you really require that the input text be uppercase, you'll need to combine this with `text-transform: uppercase;` in CSS.

Answer (score 8):

```html
1. No Capitalization
    <input autocapitalize=off/>
    <ion-input autocapitalize=off/>
    <br/>
2. Characters Capitalization
    <input autocapitalize=characters/>
    <ion-input autocapitalize=characters/>
    <br/>
3. Words Capitalization
    <input autocapitalize=words/>
    <ion-input autocapitalize=words/>
    <br/>
4. For sentence
    <input autocapitalize=sentences/>
    <ion-input autocapitalize=sentences/>
    <br/>
```

Updated as per comments for ionic just replace input with ion-input

Comment: It should be `ion-input`.

Comment: Rather than just posting a code block, also explaining *how* it solves the problem is more helpful to others.